# scraping with changing class name

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extract names, address, Role, Status, Appointed on, Resigned on (if any) from the a web page, with a code example below.

The problem is that the number of directors can be different per company, and I am not sure how pin down the number of total directors (class `appointment-1`) = x so I can loop through them.

HTLM code:

```html
<div class="appointments-list">
    <div class="appointment-1">
        <h2 class="heading-medium">
            <span id="officer-name-1">
                <a href="/officers/Oo16GI3lS3HEgrIR-kCpmLYbDWw/appointments"  onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackGoal', 5]);">BUCKSEY, Nicholas</a>
            </span>
        </h2>
        <dl>
            <dt id="officer-address-field-1">Correspondence address</dt>
            <dd class="data" id="officer-address-value-1">
1 St James&#39;s Square, London, SW1Y 4PD                    </dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="grid-row">
            <dl class="column-quarter">
                <dt>Role
                       <span id="officer-status-tag-1" class="status-tag font-xsmall">Active</span>
                </dt>
                <dd id="officer-role-1" class="data">
                    Secretary
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="column-quarter">
                <dt>Appointed on</dt>
                <dd id="officer-appointed-on-1" class="data">
                    1 June 2020
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div> 
        <div class="grid-row"></div> 
        <div class="grid-row"></div> 
        <div class="grid-row"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="appointment-2">
        <h2 class="heading-medium heading-with-border">
            <span id="officer-name-2">
                <a href="/officers/IND_i3_G7Gqq3ZzC3P0rXYbUcNU/appointments"  onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackGoal', 5]);">MATHEWS, Benedict John Spurway</a>
            </span>
        </h2>
    </h2>

    <dl>
        <dt id="officer-address-field-2">Correspondence address</dt>
        <dd class="data" id="officer-address-value-2">
1 St James&#39;s Square, London, SW1Y 4PD                    </dd>
    </dl>

    <div class="grid-row">
        <dl class="column-quarter">
            <dt>Role
                   <span id="officer-status-tag-2" class="status-tag font-xsmall">Active</span>
            </dt>
            <dd id="officer-role-2" class="data">
                Secretary
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="column-quarter">
            <dt>Appointed on</dt>
            <dd id="officer-appointed-on-2" class="data">
                7 May 2019
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div> 

    <div class="grid-row"></div> 
    <div class="grid-row"></div> 
    <div class="grid-row"></div> 
</div>
```

VBA code: I am trying to use `querySelectorall` but cannot 'identify' the correct class id.

```vb
Sub ChangeTab()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/00102498/officers"

    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    ' Dim i As Long, secNumberNodeList As Object, secNumberNode As Object
 
    Set secNumberNodeList = ie.Document.querySelectorAll("appointments-list")
 
    For Each sc In secNumberNodeList 
        Debug.Print sc.getElementById("officer-name-1")
        Debug.Print sc.getElementById("officer-address-value-1")
        Debug.Print sc.getElementById("officer-status-tag-1")
        Debug.Print sc.getElementById("officer-appointed-on-1")
        Debug.Print sc.getElementById("officer-appointed-on-1")
        Debug.Print sc.getElementById("officer-resigned-on-16")
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the robust ways how you can do this. I used XMLHttpRequest instead of IE. I've tried to show how you can make use of a loop to access the content of all the containers. Try defining other fields of your interest within the loop to parse them as well.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetInformation()
    Const URL = "https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/00102498/officers"
    Dim Http As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, I&
    Dim HtmlDoc As HTMLDocument, sName$, sAddress$

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set HtmlDoc = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".appointments-list > [class^='appointment-']")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            HtmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .Item(I).outerHTML
            sName = HtmlDoc.querySelector("h2 > span > a").innerText
            sAddress = HtmlDoc.querySelector(".data[id^='officer-address-value-']").innerText
            Debug.Print sName, sAddress
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference you need to add to execute the above script:

```
1. Microsoft XML, v6.0
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Not sure why your answer didn't show when I wrote mine. Guess you posted whilst I was writing! Apologies.

Comment: You answered it in a different angle to fix the same issue @QHarr. I don't really find any reason why you deleted it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sim, thank you very much. i am getting an error on 'sStatus = HtmlDoc.querySelector(".data[id^='officer-status-tag-']").innerText. i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Try this instead `sStatus = HtmlDoc.querySelector("span[id^='officer-status-tag-']").innerText`